# i am trying to add corousel in angular app but active class is added to all elements

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

i am trying to add corousel in angular app but for every product active class is added i want to add it at different time intervals or on click.

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div *ngFor = "let product of products">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img
              class="d-block w-100"
              src="{{product.imageUrl}}"
              alt="First slide"
              />
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div *ngFor = "let product of products;let i = index">
      <div [ngClass]="i == 0 ? 'carousel-item active' : 'carousel-item'">
          <img
          class="d-block w-100"
          src="{{product.imageUrl}}"
          alt="First slide"
          />
        </div>
    </div>
```